# Problem with a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ModeratorSpamDeleteComment


  DECLARE @CommentID int;



AS
  BEGIN
    DELETE Comments
    WHERE CommentsID=@CommentID
  END
```

It says i have an incorrect syntax near "AS" and "Declare"..

I want to deliver the store procedure the CommentID parameter and execute the delete statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
        dbo.ModeratorSpamDeleteComment
                @CommentID INT
AS
        DELETE
        FROM    Comments
        WHERE   CommentsID = @CommentID
```

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of DECLARE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ModeratorSpamDeleteComment
@CommentID int
AS


  BEGIN
    DELETE Comments
    WHERE CommentsID=@CommentID
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't `DECLARE` the arguments;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ModeratorSpamDeleteComment
( --parens are optional but clearer imo
   @CommentID int
)
AS --don't need BEGIN/END in this case

DELETE FROM Comments
   WHERE CommentsID=@CommentID
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `DECLARE` into your procedure body (between `BEGIN` and `END`). The area it's in now is for procedure parameters.